# ActiveRecord adding to negative date year

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, activerecord

I need to be able to save negative dates, but have been running into a problem: ActiveRecord is adding 1 to the year when retrieving the date from the database.

The migration uses `t.date`.

Here's a quick example:

I create and save a model with a date value of `Date.new(-44, 3, 15)`.

When inserting into the database, and inside the database, the year is correct. A manual psql check confirmed this.

However, when retrieving the date from the DB using ActiveRecord, the year is -43.

I've googled and searched SO with no results. Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: Haven't yet explored if using DateTime would make a difference... But if that's the case, it's a very frustrating difference. :/ Edit: It doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Not sure what the cause is but I would first like to ask why this needs to be true? (negative dates?) Secondly are you opposed to storing as a String and then putting in a dump and load type procedure? e.g. `def my_date=(d); @my_date = d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d");end` and `def my_date; Date.parse(@my_date); end`

Comment: That's one way to get around it... But I'd still like to know if there's a reason the simple, straight forward functionality does not work as one might predict.

Comment: Take a look at this [article](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-rails-works-type-casting) for a better idea about *"...what is causing this?"* it might help you find a more sufficient work around. Although when I interact directly with these methods the date is converted properly. Can you show the date format in the database that you manually checked?

Comment: Postgress has the date stored as `0044-03-15 BC`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. As a FYI, question titles are regular sentences, not like book titles, so we use regular sentence capitalization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-new

> ```
> ...BCE years are counted astronomically.
> ...the year before the year 1 is the year zero, 
> and the year preceding the year zero is the year -1.
> ```

Researching this I thought you had discovered a defect in `Date#parse`, then I thought it was working 'as designed', now I am not sure anymore :(

```
Date.parse('2015-06-15 CE') == Date.new(2015, 6, 15)
# => true

Date.parse('0000-01-01 CE') == Date.new(0, 1, 1)
# => true

Date.parse('0002-01-01 BCE') == Date.new(-1, 1, 1)
# => true

Date.parse('0000-01-01 CE') == Date.parse('0001-01-01 BCE')
# => true

Date.parse('0001-01-01 BCE') == Date.new(0, 1, 1)
# => true
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomical_year_numbering

> The year 1 BC/BCE is numbered 0, the year 2 BC is numbered −1

So it appears to work 'as designed', but maybe not as expected

```
# The year 1 BC/BCE is numbered 0
Date.parse('0001-01-01 BCE') == Date.new(0, 1, 1)

# the year 2 BC is numbered −1
Date.parse('0002-01-01 BCE') == Date.new(-1, 1, 1)
```

---

What does this mean for you and your rails app?

User input is most likely submitted in the format '0044-03-15 BC' as a string (params), which is assigned to a model attribute.

```
x = Widget.create(date_column: '0044-03-15 BC')

x.date_column
 => Wed, 15 Mar -0043

x.attributes_before_type_cast['date_column']
 => "0044-03-15 BC"

x.attributes_before_type_cast['date_column'].to_date
 => Wed, 15 Mar -0043
```

guessing `to_date` is also using `Date.parse`

I'm really not sure how the correct value gets stored in postgres, but rails is going to use `Date.parse` on that value and be off by a year when displaying the users entered date (BCE only).

---

some possible hacky workarounds

1) Store the values as integers

```
class Whatever < ActiveRecord::Base
  # 'date' column -> the_date stored as an integer

  # override the columns 'getter' method
  def the_date
    the_time = Time.at(self[:the_date])
    Date.new(the_time.year, the_time.month, the_time.day)
  end
end

# Time#to_i - epoch time
x = Whatever.create(the_date: Time.new(-44, 3, 15, 0, 0, 0).to_i)
```

2) Store the year, month, day as separate database fields?

```
class Whatever < ActiveRecord::Base
  # 'date' stored as 3 integer columns -> the_date_year, the_date_month, the_date_day

  # use this in views, etc...
  def the_date
    Date.new(the_date_year, the_date_month, the_date_day)
  end
end
```

hopefully somebody else has a better solution...